# Zebra MC40 listen to PTT button during sleep

Tags: android, motorola, motorola-emdk

I'm new to using/developing apps for the Zebra MC40. I want to be able to listen to the PTT button when the device is in sleep mode. 
I am able to listen to it when my activity is visible, but I want to be able to use the PTT button without the activity needing to be visible.

I would like to learn of the possible options both with and without using EMDK.

Any pointers appreciated!